# Loop structure in select clause

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I am writing a query where the number of columns is not fixed and dependent on the number of values provided by another table. Hence I am not able to write a static query that specifies the number of columns being selected. I need to apply something similar to a loop structure where the number of columns are created dynamically depending on the values provided. Is it possible to use loop structure in select clause ? In case this is not possible then I may have to use a procedure to build the query dynamically.
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL : Select a dynamic number of rows as columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208197/sql-select-a-dynamic-number-of-rows-as-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your query dynamically and execute it using 'EXECUTE IMMEDIATE'. Refer http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm for more details