# SQL:Using the data as a column

Tags: sql, database

been searching for this but I havent found a solution yet. Lets say I have a table person and a table cars. A person can have many cars. Table Person looks like this:

```
ID Name
```

Table Cars look like this:

```
ID P_ID Car_Brand PlateNum
```

Cars can have a value like this:

```
ID:1
P_ID:1
Car_Brand:Toyota
PlateNum: 12345


ID:2
P_ID:1
Car_Brand:Ford
PlateNum:456789
```

I want to create a query that would have this result:

```
person.id person.name ford.platenum toyota.platenum
   1         John            456789        12345
```

A person will always have these 2 car brands. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I don't agree this being a good idea. This topic might help you though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208197/sql-select-a-dynamic-number-of-rows-as-columns

Comment: Hi, table structure is rigid and cant update the schema. This would have been easy if it were normalized but thats out of the question at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    p.id, 
    name, 
    ford.platenum, 
    toyota.platenum
from
    person p
    join cars ford on p.ID = ford.P_ID and ford.Car_Brand = 'Ford'
    join cars toyota on p.ID = toyota.P_ID and toyota.Car_Brand = 'Toyota'
```

Comment: This only works if the only cars are toyota and ford. What happens if you introduce another 20 car brands?